# WHY is value by reference not holding data after returning from function

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I have a function and give this function a variable by reference. As long as I'm in the function, the veriable holds the data I expect, but after returning from the function, the referenced value does hold some strange data... I don't see the error in my function... Can anyone show me the problem? The debug output shows the problem... The group values in X2 and X3 should match, but they don't...

Here I call the main function:

```
Dim groupVar As Integer
Dim variationGroups() As Integer    

Call GetUniqueVariationGroups(variationGroups)
For countVarGroup = 1 To UBound(variationGroups)
    Debug.Print "X3: index = " & countVarGroup & " | group = " & variationGroups(countVarGroup)
Next countVarGroup
```

And the main function is following (btw, `variation` is a custom class and `variation(i).group` is an `Integer`)

```
Public Function GetUniqueVariationGroups(ByRef groups() As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim exists As Boolean

For i = 1 To UBound(variation)
    Debug.Print "X1: " & variation(i).group
Next i

ReDim groups(0)

For i = 1 To UBound(variation)

    exists = False
    For j = 1 To UBound(groups)
        If variation(i).group = groups(j) Then
            exists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If Not exists Then
        ReDim groups(UBound(groups) + 1)
        groups(UBound(groups)) = variation(i).group
        Debug.Print "X2: size/index = " & UBound(groups) & " | group= " & groups(UBound(groups))
    End If

Next i

End Function
```

And here is the debug output:

```
X1: 1
X1: 4
X1: 4
X1: 5
X2: size/index = 1 | group= 1
X2: size/index = 2 | group= 4
X2: size/index = 3 | group= 5
X3: index = 1 | group= 0
X3: index = 2 | group= 0
X3: index = 3 | group= 5
```

Comment: For a start I think you should be using Redim Preserve when resizing the array.

Comment: that's not just the start, that's already the solution... I just read the documentation for preserve and now understand what the problem was... so thanks a lot

Comment: @prom85: I take it from context that the final phrase was sincere and not sarcastic - however it doesn't read that way.

Comment: sorry... didn't see that. It was meant sincere of course, because I really didn't know it before and this little extra information solved my problem...